# When do you use 'nom de plume' vs. 'pen name' vs. 'pseudonym'?

Tags: word-usage, contemporary-english

Dictionaries usually treat *nom de plume* as synonymous with 'pen name' or 'pseudonym'.  Example from [Merriam Webster's dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nom%20de%20plume):

> **Definition of nom de plume**: a name that a writer uses instead of his or her real name : PSEUDONYM, PEN NAME

In what context would you use one rather than the other?  Is it a matter of regional preferences (ex. one is more prevalent in Britain and the other in America)?

Comment: Nom de plume and pen name are for writers but pseudonym is more general.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A **pseudonym** is any time you are using a name other than your own.

A **pen name** is when an author publishes under a different name.

A **nom de plume** is when a *pretentious* author publishes under a different name.

Generally a pseudonym has the intention of concealing who the real person is. With a pen name or nom de plume it may be for purposes other than concealment.

Comment: I find several recent articles about famous writers: [here](https://www.npr.org/2015/11/02/453885684/j-k-rolling-on-her-nom-de-plume-robert-galbraith) and [here](https://www.readersdigest.co.uk/culture/books/book-reviews/7-famous-authors-and-their-noms-de-plume); it's the *article writer* who used the term *nom de plume* in the article title, although they then use "pen name" in the body of the articles.  [This article](https://artuk.org/discover/stories/ten-women-who-used-pseudonyms-and-one-man) use all 3. Would you say it's the article writer that's pretentious, or the writers mentioned?

Comment: False dichotomy: "Would you say it's the article writer that's pretentious, or the writers mentioned?"  Why not all of the above?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you write under a *pen name* rather than a *nom de plume.* The French don't say *nom de plume*: they say **Nom de guerre**. *Nom de plume* was made up by English-speakers 150 years ago. As H.W.Fowler said (and [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=nom%20de%20plume) mentions) it is "ridiculous for English writers to use a French phrase that does not come from France."

As Stuart F said, *pseudonym* is more general. You can write, or do anything you like, under a pseudonym.

Answer (score -7):

I recommend: when in doubt use the most common one...

[image: Ngram]

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nom%20de%20plume%2Cpseudonym%2Cpen%20name&year_start=1860&year_end=2000&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

Comment: As "pen name" and "pseudonym" are not interchangeable, their relative frequencies of use aren't relevant.

Comment: Going with the crowd is good advice, so I voted this back up. This Wikipedia bio of Stephen Marlowe may provide some useful context. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Marlowe